# Automarking directories in Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml, src

I have a little project that has the next structure:

[image: structure]

I'm using Maven to build it. For some reason every time I make changes to `pom.xml` IntellijIDEA marks `java` folder as source directory and unmarks the `src` folder. Why it does so and how to fix or avoid it?

Comment: Because it has to be this way unless you want to override maven default directory structure

Comment: But it looks like default structure, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it's the default folder structure of maven but you should mark `java` as the source root